# Changing tick labels in loglog plot

Tags: python, label, axis, ticker, xticks

The default plot puts scientific notation in the x axis labels. These labels are 2,3,4, and 6, so that doesn't make much sense. Traditional methods seem to rely on the 'ScalarFormatter' which, is not used in log space...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


nu = np.array([34., 10.,  3.,  2.,  1.])
bins = np.array([1.73619534, 2.6928761 , 3.64955685, 4.6062376 , 6.5195991 ])
x_err = (bins[2]-bins[1])/2*(nu/nu)

def func_powerlaw(x, m, c):
    return x**m * c
target_func = func_powerlaw
popt, pcov = curve_fit(target_func, bins, nu, maxfev=2000, p0 = np.asarray([-1,34]))
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
x_line = np.linspace(1.7,6.7,41)
fit_curve = target_func(x_line, *popt)
fit_curve_u = target_func(x_line, popt[0]+perr[0],popt[1]+perr[1])
fit_curve_l = target_func(x_line, popt[0]-perr[0],popt[1]-perr[1])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# plt.loglog(x,f_x, 'b')
ax.errorbar(bins,nu, yerr=None, xerr=x_err, marker='.',linewidth = 0, elinewidth=2, color = 'k')
ax.loglog(x_line, fit_curve, '-')
ax.fill_between(x_line, fit_curve_l, fit_curve_u,alpha = 0.2)
# labels = ['high', 'low', 37337]
ax.set_xscale('log') # yes this is redundant
ax.set_xticks([2,3,4,5]) #this line ends up not working ):
ax.set_xlim([1.5,8.5])
```

[plot you get from running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn9wa.png)

Answer (score 0):

This question is a dup, found the answer here: [How to change log-scale tick labels in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671786/how-to-change-log-scale-tick-labels-in-matplotlib)

Answer:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter, NullFormatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:.1f}'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())
```